# many-to-many in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i am new to hibernate. i have three table(course-student-course student).the following is my codes but it didnot work. i have written the cfg.xml too. i think my problem is my hbm files but i could not solve.

```
public class Student {
private int student_id;
private String student_name;
public Student()
{

}
public Student(int id,String name)
{
this.student_id=id;
this.student_name=name;
}
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();
public int getstudentid()
{
    return student_id;
}
public void setstudentid(int id)

{
    this.student_id=id;
}
public String getstudentname()
{
    return student_name;
}
public void setstudentname(String name)
{
    this.student_name=name;
}
public Set<Course> getcourse()
{
    return courses;
}
public void setcourse(Set<Course> courses)
{
    this.courses=courses;
}
}

public class Course {
    private int course_id;
    private String course_name;
    private Set<Student> students= new HashSet<Student>();
public Course()
{

}
public Course(int id, String name)
{
    this.course_id=id;
    this.course_name=name;
}
public int getcourseid()
{
    return course_id;
}
public void setcourseid(int id)
{
    this.course_id=id;
}
public String getcoursename()
{
    return course_name;
}
public void setcoursename(String name)
{
    this.course_name=name;
}
public Set<Student> getstudents()
{
    return students;
}
public void setstudents(Set<Student> students)
{
    this.students=students;
}
}
```

hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated May 29, 2012 3:19:54 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping package="first">
    <class name="Course" table="COURSE">
        <id name="course_id" type="int" access="field">
            <column name="COURSE_ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="course_name" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="COURSE_NAME" />
        </property>
        <set name="students" table="student_course"
inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="join" cascade="all">
<key column="student_id" />
<many-to-many column="course_id" class="Course" />
</set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated May 29, 2012 3:19:54 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping package="first">
    <class name="Student" table="STUDENT">
        <id name="student_id" type="int" access="field">
            <column name="STUDENT_ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="student_name" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="STUDENT_NAME" />
        </property>
        <set name="courses" table="student_course"
inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="join" cascade="all">
<key column="student_id" />
<many-to-many column="course_id" class="Course" />
</set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my managed code:

```
public class ManageStudent {
    private static SessionFactory sf;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().addResource("first/Student.hbm.xml").addResource("first/Course.hbm.xml");
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
    configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
    System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }


    System.out.println("Hibernate Many to Many Mapping Example Using Xml ");

    Session session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Student s1=new Student(1,"mina");
    Student s2=new Student(2,"samira");

    Course c1=new Course(10,"math");
    Course c2=new Course(11,"sport");

    s1.getcourse().add(c2);
    s2.getcourse().add(c1);
    s2.getcourse().add(c2);

    session.save(s1);
    session.save(s2);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    }
}
```

my error is:

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at first.ManageStudent.main(ManageStudent.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at first.ManageStudent.main(ManageStudent.java:18)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:158)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for courses in class first.Student
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:436)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:82)
    ... 18 more
```

please help me.
my new error :

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in SYSTEM.COURSE for column COURSE_NAME. Found: number, expected: varchar2(255 char)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at first.ManageStudent.main(ManageStudent.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in SYSTEM.COURSE for column COURSE_NAME. Found: number, expected: varchar2(255 char)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at first.ManageStudent.main(ManageStudent.java:18)
```

Comment: place your complete stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code snippet I can see one thing wrong:

1. `<class name="rStudent" table="STUDENT">` when class name is Student, change this and rerun.

This exception is generally thrown when hibernate doesnt find a No Arg Constructor or you have a cyclic dependency, since in your code I see that No Arg constructor is available and for initialization no cyclic dependency is present, correcting name should help resolve this issue.

As per edit:

Your getter, setter for courses is not correct

Instead of

```
public Set<Course> getcourse() // this should be getCourses
{
    return courses;
}
public void setcourse(Set<Course> courses) // this should be setCourses
{
    this.courses=courses;
}
```

On similar lines please change following in your Courses.java

```
public Set<Student> getstudents() // Make it getStudents
{
    return students;
}
public void setstudents(Set<Student> students) // Make it setStudents
{
    this.students=students;
}
```

Your getter, setter dont follow correct naming convention which is required for hibernate.

Check your getter, setter for Student with the code below:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Student {

    private int    student_id;
    private String  student_name;
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    public Student() {

    }
    public Student(int id, String name) {
        this.student_id = id;
        this.student_name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the student_id
     */
    public int getStudent_id() {
        return student_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param student_id the student_id to set
     */
    public void setStudent_id(int student_id) {
        this.student_id = student_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the student_name
     */
    public String getStudent_name() {
        return student_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param student_name the student_name to set
     */
    public void setStudent_name(String student_name) {
        this.student_name = student_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the courses
     */
    public Set<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    /**
     * @param courses the courses to set
     */
    public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}
```

Similarly for Course

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Course {
    private int          course_id;
    private String       course_name;
    private Set<Student>    students    = new HashSet<Student>();
    public Course() {

    }
    public Course(int id, String name) {
        this.course_id = id;
        this.course_name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the course_id
     */
    public int getCourse_id() {
        return course_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param course_id the course_id to set
     */
    public void setCourse_id(int course_id) {
        this.course_id = course_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the course_name
     */
    public String getCourse_name() {
        return course_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param course_name the course_name to set
     */
    public void setCourse_name(String course_name) {
        this.course_name = course_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the students
     */
    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    /**
     * @param students the students to set
     */
    public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
}
```

Comment: the name was correct. it is Student. but the problem did not solve.

Comment: what did you exactly mean? i cannot understand stack trace.

Comment: paste the complete exception that is coming

Comment: i have this error now:Wrong column type in SYSTEM.COURSE for column COURSE_NAME. Found: number, expected: varchar2(255 char)

Comment: your gettter, setter have problem check classes that I have placed as part of edit

Comment: unfortunately i have this error yet:Wrong column type in SYSTEM.COURSE for column COURSE_NAME. Found: number, expected: varchar2(255 char) as part of edit.

Comment: Okay your database table has number as the data type make it varchar

Comment: i changed course_name data type in oracle. and my problem is solved. thank you mprabhat

Answer (score 1):

There's several problems I can spot:

Your `.hbm.xml` has the following: `<set name="courses" …>`. The value of the `name` attribute has to be the name of the property on the entity. Your `Student` class however only has the methods `getcourse()` and `setcourse()`. This is why the stack trace says:

> Could not find a getter for courses in class first.Student

The correct method names to define a property `courses` would be `getCourses()` and `setCourses()`. It's the getter/setter method names that are important for *properties*, not the name of the field. (You should correct this for all getters and setters you have.)

Another thing is that your naming convention doesn't follow the official convention. In Java, the standard is to camelCase fields and methods. While this isn't as important for fields, it's necessary when using the JavaBean specification which a lot of frameworks rely on.